# Error: mat-form-field, mat-selection-list must contain a MatFormFieldControl

Tags: checkbox, angular7, form-control

I am trying to add a checkbox and attach to a formfield. I am using angular 7.
I am using tags mat-form-field, and for this I am getting error

> mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl.

I have checked my Component code and made sure FormControl exist. Though it is not very clear but add formControl "mat-selection-list"

```
//DECLARE CONTROL
    preexistingControl = new FormControl('',[Validators.required]);
// CHECKBOX DATA
    preExistingCondList: PreExistingCond[] = [
            {id:'0' ,value:'None'},
            {id:'1' ,value:'Arthritis'}, 
            {id:'2' ,value:'Asthma'},];
//ADD TO FormGroup
    preexistingControl:this.preexistingControl,
```

HTML code

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-selection-list #preConditions placeholder="PreExisting Conditions" [formControl]="preexistingControl">
        <mat-list-option *ngFor="let preExistingCond of preExistingCondList">
                        {{preExistingCond.value}}
        </mat-list-option>
    </mat-selection-list>
</mat-form-field>
```

It is throwing following error:

```
ERROR Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl.
    at getMatFormFieldMissingControlError (form-field.es5.js:119)
    at MatFormField.push../node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/form-field.es5.js.MatFormField._validateControlChild (form-field.es5.js:764)
    at MatFormField.push../node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/form-field.es5.js.MatFormField.ngAfterContentInit (form-field.es5.js:453)
    at callProviderLifecycles (core.js:22311)
    at callElementProvidersLifecycles (core.js:22292)
    at callLifecycleHooksChildrenFirst (core.js:22282)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23213)
    at callViewAction (core.js:23450)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:23392)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23215)
```

I have check the formControl exist and the ref id is correct.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to do this with a small work around, this applies to any material components that are not supported. You can nest them within a mat-form-field like so.

```
    <mat-form-field [formGroup]="formGroup" class="mat-form-field--no-underline">
        <!-- Important part, input with matInput -->
        <input matInput style="display: none!important">
        <mat-selection-list #preConditions [formControl]="preexistingControl" [(ngModel)]="controlAnswer.value">
            <mat-list-option *ngFor="let preExistingCond of preExistingCondList">
                {{preExistingCond.value}}
            </mat-list-option>
        </mat-selection-list>
     </mat-form-field>
```

And then you need the following CSS

```
  .mat-form-field--no-underline .mat-form-field-underline {
     background-color: transparent !important;
  }
```

If the style does not apply you can use ngdeep to have it apply

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation at : https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview

The following Angular Material components are designed to work inside a

```
<mat-form-field>
<input matNativeControl> & <textarea matNativeControl>
<select matNativeControl>
<mat-select>
<mat-chip-list>

<mat-selection-list> is not supported for now.
```